# How to turn a dataframe with a list column into a dash Data Table, with the list contents as rows?

Tags: pandas, plotly-dash

I have a dataframe with the columns

```
   App  | Week   | Top Users
 -------+--------+------------------------------
  App 1 | Week 1 |[1st user, 2nd user, 3rd user]
```

that shows the top 3 users of each app per week. The Top Users cells contain a list of the top 3 users.

Now i want to build a dash Data Table that gets updated when i select the App from a dropdown list.

I am trying to make the table look like this

```
 Week 1  | Week 2  | Week 3  | Week 4
---------+---------+------- -+----------
 1st user| 1st user| 1st user| 1st user
---------+---------+------- -+----------  
 2nd user| 2nd user| 2nd user| 2nd user
---------+---------+------- -+----------
 3rd user| 3rd user| 3rd user| 3rd user
    

    app = dash.Dash()

    top_users['Week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(top_users['Week']).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    app_options = []
    for apps in top_users['App'].unique():
        app_options.append({'label':str(apps), 'value':apps})

    weeks = []
    for week in top_users['Week'].unique():
        weeks.append(week)


    app.layout = html.Div(children=[
                        dash_table.DataTable(
                        id='top-users',
                        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in weeks],
                        fixed_rows={'headers': True}
                        ) ,
                        dcc.Dropdown(id='app-picker', options=app_options),                               
                        ])

    @app.callback(
    Output('top-users', 'data'),
    Input('app-picker', 'value'))
    def update_table(selected_app):    
        data = top_users.loc[top_users['App']==selected_app]
        return data.to_dict('records')
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(host="127.0.0.1", port=8060)
```

The code above doesn't show anything at all